# Phonegap Windows Phone barcode scanning

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, barcode-scanner

The Phonegap plugins univers seems to have become a bit confused recently.

I've successfully implemented barcode scanning on an Android/iOS Phonegap app last year. I used the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins but it is now deprecated. The new repository doesn't seem to offer any WP8 solution.

Is there currently any stable way to implement barcode scanning for a Windows Phone 8 Phonegap Application?

Answer (score 2):

How about this application:
https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner

Also check this answer:
[The Phonegap Barcode Scanner don't recognize any barcode on windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435421/the-phonegap-barcode-scanner-dont-recognize-any-barcode-on-windows-phone)