# Cordova Barcode Scanner - Camera too dark on Windows 8

Tags: cordova, barcode

I'm using the Cordova Barcode Scanner plugin in my Cordova app but I'm having an issue with running it on regular Windows 8 (NOT Windows Phone 8). About 90% of the time I try to use it, the view from the camera is extremely underexposed and the screen is mostly black. The other 10% of the time it seems to be dark for a second, then adjust as I'd expect.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: can you share snapshot?

Comment: have you checked ZXing Barcode Scanner ? https://github.com/zxing/zxing and also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435421/the-phonegap-barcode-scanner-dont-recognize-any-barcode-on-windows-phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. After much investigation I have discovered the PhotoCameraSource property was not set. After setting this to VideoPreview it worked flawlessly.

I've made a pull request to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/pull/207